# What is the limit to number of words in Facebook API in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, facebook

In my iPhone app, I have to pass my text into Facebook API. but due to some reason the text with more number of words does not display in Facebook.

So is there any limit to number of words when we pass the text through Facebook API?

If yes, what is the limit for number of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size is 420 chars.

Comment: Hey if I want to count character in my iphone app how can I do it programmatically? Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Use -[NSString length] to count characters.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: thanx Alex Martini. I will try that

Comment: Thanks Alex Martini and Marc :]